# Why won't this Verilog code compile?

Tags: verilog

The part that causes problems is `c[1] = p[0] + g[0] & c0;`. What's wrong with it?

```
module CLA_gen(p, g, c0, c);
input [3:0] p;
input [3:0] g;
input c0;
output reg [4:1] c;
begin
c[1] = p[0] + g[0] & c0;
end
endmodule
```

Comment: What problems does it cause? What compiler error(s) do you get?

Comment: Agreed, in general it is good form to include an output errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing your always block and its sensitivity list.

```
always @(*)
  c[1] = p[0] + g[0] & c0;
```

In the code you posted above, you don't necessarily need the begin/end since you only have one line.  But it doesn't not hurt to add it in there.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely want to change:

```
begin
```

to:

```
always @* begin
```

Every `begin/end` must be part of another construct, such as `always`, `initial`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the begin and end
declare c only as an output

follow this

```
module CLA_gen(p, g, c0, c);
input [3:0] p;
input [3:0] g;
input c0;
output [4:1] c;
assign c[1] = p[0] + g[0] & c0;
endmodule
```

Answer (score -1):

You might need to use <= instead of = .

Comment: We don't know what he is modeling at this point so we cannot make that judgement yet.